# GGplot2: arranging bar plot accumulating to 100% in a circular manner

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data which are 8 factors that have been rated 1-4 and I am interested in the distribution of those ratings for each of those factors.

In a classic barplot, I would display them like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBN4o.png). However, there is also spatial information and I would like to reflect that in my plot.

My current code gives me this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USGhg.png) whereas I am trying to reach something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTOZq.png), but obviously filled with the correct proportions and not necessarily square.

The entire code to replicate all 3 plots is [here](https://pastebin.com/67NHE2hx). This is what generates the wrong plot:

`d <-qplot(x, y, data=df, fill = rating)  +  geom_col()`

I would really appreciate any help

Comment: Can you post this spatial data?

Comment: The objects were presented basically as 8 positions on a clock. So it would be relevant to know for instance that class 1 would be "up and to the right" of class 3. 
The relevant data from the pastebin is:
'x <- c(5,3.5,0,-3.5,-5,-3.5,0,3.5)
y <- c(0,3.5,5,3.5,0,-3.5,-5,-3.5)'

Comment: Aren't these two dimensions?

Comment: Sory if I don't explain it clearly. Together, they should give one spatial information - the position on a coordinate system.

It is a bunch of objects presented different places on a screen. I want to know if the position/category where the object was presented makes a difference for how that object is rated.

Comment: There's no `class` in data that you posted

Comment: If you run the data from pastebin, you have a dataframe "df" with the following?

'> str(df)
'data.frame': 32 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ class     : Factor w/ 8 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ proportion: num  0.33 0.424 0.131 0.115 0.412 ...
 $ rating    : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
 $ x         : num  5 5 5 5 3.5 3.5 3.5 3.5 0 0 ...
 $ y         : num  0 0 0 0 3.5 3.5 3.5 3.5 5 5 ...'

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872193/circular-stacked-bar-plot-in-r

Comment: Thanks - that seems at least to be the gist of it.

Comment: @SimonHviidDelPin it seems that you have gotten a nice solution for your problem. That solution can be modified quite easily too. I like it! If you are happy with the solution, please mark it as answer to your question. While you are at it, please edit your question and paste relevant data to your question such that relevant information will not get lost when Pastepin expires. This will make your question helpful for others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

class <- (c(rep(1,4),rep(2,4), rep(3,4), rep(4,4), rep(5,4), rep(6,4), rep(7,4), rep(8,4)))
rating <- rep(c(1,2,3,4),8)
proportion <-  c(0.3304, 0.4241, 0.1305, 0.1150,
             0.4119, 0.4016, 0.1026, 0.0839,
             0.2831, 0.4279, 0.1493, 0.1397,
             0.1150, 0.1305, 0.4241, 0.3304,
             0.1305, 0.1150, 0.4241, 0.3304,
             0.3304, 0.4241, 0.1150, 0.1305,
             0.1150, 0.3304, 0.4241, 0.1305,
             0.1150, 0.1305, 0.4241, 0.3304)
df <- data.frame(class,proportion,rating)
df$class <- as.factor(df$class)
df$rating <- as.factor(df$rating)

lev <- levels(df$class)
nlev <- length(lev)
angs <- seq(pi/2,-pi-2*pi/nlev,-2*pi/nlev)
xpos <- cos(angs)*.4+0.5
ypos <- sin(angs)*.4+0.5

grid.newpage()

for (k in 1:nlev) {
  pushViewport( viewport(x=xpos[k], y=ypos[k], w=.1, h=.2) )
  p <- ggplot(aes(x=1, y=proportion, fill=rating), data=subset(df,class==lev[k]))  +  
       geom_col(show.legend=F) + theme_void() + ggtitle(lev[k])
  g <- ggplotGrob(p)
  grid.draw(g)
  popViewport()
}
```

[image]